# How to hide a keypad for IOS in Titanium without using 'blur'

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Can anyone please let me know how to hide the keypad without using 'blur' in titanium for IOS. 
My scenario is I have a textfield, When I scan an item, that value will be shown on textfield. When textfield is focused, the scanner will be activated. In this scenario i need to focus the textfield, but should not show the keypad.

Can any one please share your ideas.

Thanks,
Swathi.

Comment: You could recreate this without a textfield, since you can't resign the first responder status of the textField in Titanium like you can in Objc or swift currently without modifying the base source code i'd go down a different route. You can create a label inside a view with a border to emulate the textField and listen to the click event on the view, when the scanner returns it's value you can set the labels text property. If you need an animation like a cursor you can use a custom animation to show and hide a 1px line at the start of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to hide keypad when textfield is focused on iOS. It is a system thing.

I think your approach is wrong. Why do you need textfield if you don't want to type text there?
Instead of it:
 - create label (or label inside view) with proper background (looking like textfield),
 - add 'click' event which will start scanning (i suppose you have that functionality for 'focus' event),
 - if you need cursor blinking than create animation next to label.